# text to speech isn't working with no error

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an assistant. But when I work on "Text to speech" I got some trouble.
My code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Sally sells seashells by the seashore.') 
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

When I run the code, nothing happen.
[The terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgBso.png)
I have already download pyttsx3 and pypiwin32. I also checked the volume.
Please have me TT!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('dummy') or engine = pyttsx.init('dummy')
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Look like it didn't work. Nothing happened either. I tried to install PyAudio too but it didn't work.